# Export release build is creating app directory not dmg

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

Sometimes over the last month Flash Builder started exporting an Mac "App directory" rather than a DMG.

I'm not sure what has changed but I'd like to be able to create DMG again. Anyone know the cause or how to change it back?

The file size was 5.7MB DMG and now it's a 77MB directory and 32MB compressed zip with no install process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong export option.

Export to signed native installer. That creates a DMG. 
×
You can accept your own answer in 2 days

I was using the wrong export option.

Export to signed native installer. That creates a DMG.

> You can accept your own answer in 2 days